# How could i make it so that when i press a button the images will switch?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The way i want the gallery page to work is that when the button is pressed, the image will bring the picture to the middle and make it the same CSS(size and white shadow) and then the other images will be with the other CSS (smaller with black shadow)

HTML code:

```
    <img id="Football" src="https://w-dog.net/wallpapers/3/12/331652870386587/club-stadium-sees-camp-nou-football-game-wallpaper-the-field-camp-nou-barcelona-spain-barcelona-the-player-match-sports-andres-iniesta.jpg" alt="Football">

    <img id="Boxing" src="http://i.lv3.hbo.com/assets/images/sports/boxing/fights/2015-05-02-mayweather-vs-pacquiao/slideshow/mayweather-vs-pacquiao-ss-03-1024.jpg" alt="Boxing">

    <img id="Basketball" src="http://wallpapercave.com/wp/WNc38uX.jpg" alt="Basketball">
```

CSS code:

```
#Boxing{
  width:550px;
  height:300px;
  position:absolute; 
  margin-left:-200px;
  margin-top:350px;
  border-radius:10px;
  z-index:-1;
  opacity:0.8;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 100px black;
}

#Football{
  width:550px;
  height:400px;
  position:relative; 
  margin-left:550px;
  margin-top:300px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px white;
  border-radius:10px;

}

#Basketball{
  width:550px;
  height:300px;
  position:absolute; 
  margin-left:-900px;
  margin-top:350px;
  border-radius:10px;
  z-index:-1;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 100px black;
  opacity:0.9;

}
```

Comment: Show us the js you've got so far.

Comment: i actually have none, im a beginner at javascript

Comment: Ok, you could try using a class to determine what it should look like, have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-class-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to do some research on JavaScript, there are some topics off to the side here that will help you. It might be easier to use jQuery for something like this.

For instance you probably want to select the button and listen for a press, then when the button listener hears a press it will switch the URL of the image to a different image that you have stored, or you can switch one to display, and the other to display none. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, where the class `.show` controls if an image should be shown.

```js
let currImage = 0

const changeImage = _ => {
  const images = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#ImgContainer > img'))
  images[currImage].classList.remove('show')
  images[currImage = (currImage+1)%images.length].classList.add('show')
}
```

```css
#ImgContainer {
  width: 550px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 3em 2em;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 100px black;
}

#ImgContainer > img {width: 100%;height: 100%;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;display: block;margin:0}

#ImgContainer > img:not(.show) {display:none}

#Boxing {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

#Football {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px white;
}

#Basketball {
  opacity: 0.9;
}
```

```html
<section id="ImgContainer">
  <img id="Football" class='show' src="https://w-dog.net/wallpapers/3/12/331652870386587/club-stadium-sees-camp-nou-football-game-wallpaper-the-field-camp-nou-barcelona-spain-barcelona-the-player-match-sports-andres-iniesta.jpg" alt="Football">

  <img id="Boxing" src="http://i.lv3.hbo.com/assets/images/sports/boxing/fights/2015-05-02-mayweather-vs-pacquiao/slideshow/mayweather-vs-pacquiao-ss-03-1024.jpg" alt="Boxing">

  <img id="Basketball" src="http://wallpapercave.com/wp/WNc38uX.jpg" alt="Basketball">
</section>

<button onclick='changeImage()'>Click Me</button>
```

***Note:*** Click **`Run Code Snippet`** to see the result

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer can be like this. Just add an onclick functionality to the button. Here's your HTML

```
<img id="Football" src="https://w-dog.net/wallpapers/3/12/331652870386587/club-stadium-sees-camp-nou-football-game-wallpaper-the-field-camp-nou-barcelona-spain-barcelona-the-player-match-sports-andres-iniesta.jpg" alt="Football">

<img id="Boxing" src="http://i.lv3.hbo.com/assets/images/sports/boxing/fights/2015-05-02-mayweather-vs-pacquiao/slideshow/mayweather-vs-pacquiao-ss-03-1024.jpg" alt="Boxing">

<img id="Basketball" src="http://wallpapercave.com/wp/WNc38uX.jpg" alt="Basketball">


<button id="Save">Click Me</button>
```

Here's how the JS is.

```
 document.getElementById("Save").onclick  = function() {
document.getElementById('Football').src = 'http://cdn.gsmarena.com/imgroot/reviews/17/htc-u11-galaxy-s8plus/-728x314/gsmarena_002.jpg';
document.getElementById('Boxing').src = 'http://cdn.gsmarena.com/imgroot/news/17/05/samsung-galaxy-s8-dxo/-344x215/gsmarena_001.jpg';
document.getElementById('Basketball').src = 'http://cdn.gsmarena.com/imgroot/news/16/06/zenfone-max-marshmallow/-344x215/gsmarena_001.jpg';
}
```

Here's the JSfiddle for reference. https://jsfiddle.net/soqrcwhq/